# SQL querying on separate parts of a timestamp

Tags: sql, bigdata, presto, treasure-data

I have a reservations table that has the resource reserved and a timestamp attached to each reservation.

```
 reservation_table

resource | timestamp
```

I want to be able to break down the utilization of each resource on a per month, per hour, per resource basis.

Is it possible to do a a SQL query that gives me the following example output for example(simplified data, i actually have a time stamp in the database but need it separated out via month and hours)?

```
Month | Hour | Resource | Utilization
  1   |  1   |    1     |      x
  1   |  1   |    2     |      x
  1   |  2   |    1     |      x
  1   |  2   |    2     |      x
  1   |  3   |    1     |      x 
  1   |  3   |    2     |      x
```

I feel like this is not achievable?

Comment: SQL Server, sqlite, and prestodb are three very different products.  I have removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the one that you are actually using.  And what you want to do is readily accomplished in SQL.

Comment: What SQL Platform are you using?

Comment: You can always format the timestamp, e.g. yyyymm to find the per month use, but I don't know how good that is performance-wise.

Comment: updated tags, thanks!

Comment: You want the second column to be the hour of the day? What does *utilization* mean here, and how do you calculate it by hand? Paste CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements to help people answer you.

Comment: Yes hour of the day. you can ignore utilization for now. I mostly just want to be able to have it by month, by hour of day, by resource